# clear rows of child elements in variable width parent

Tags: jquery, css-float

Using jQuery 1.6.2

I have a variable number of floated divs inside a parent. The parent *may* have a fixed width but also may not.

I want to use jQuery to work out what number of divs are in one row, then insert a div with clear property set to both, so that the children may have variable heights and not make a mess of everything, and the parent may have a variable width.

It's a simple thing to do either in the markup or server side scripting *if* you know the width of the div and if you know how many children you want in a row - but what if everything is a bit more liquid?

Is there a simple way to do this, or am I going to have to do some working out of all the widths involved and a bit of clever maths to decide where to put the clear divs?

Comment: the php solution when knowing the width of the parent div and how many child divs i want in a row, as stated in OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Sample jQuery plugin** (couldn't come up with a better plugin name):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        addLineBreak: function (elementToInject) {
            var minLeft = $(this).position().left;

            return $(this).each(function () {
                var position = $(this).position();
                if (position.left > minLeft && $(this).prev().position().left >= position.left) {
                    $(elementToInject).insertBefore(this);
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**Usage**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.addLineBreak.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                // '.inner' is the selector for the child elements!
                $('.inner').addLineBreak('<div class="clear"></div>');

                // on resize, remove the clear-elements, and inject new ones
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    $('#tmp .clear').remove();
                    $('.inner').addLineBreak('<div class="clear"></div>');
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: black;
            }

            .inner {
                float: left;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #efefef;
            }

            .clear {
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="tmp">
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 25; $i += 1): ?>
                <div class="inner" style="width: <?php echo rand(100, 150); ?>px; height: <?php echo rand(100, 150); ?>px"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```